# Currency Conversion

Tags: currency

For building a Currency conversion function , we will be needing exchange rates on an hourly basis to be stored in SFDC. Is this going to be a manual task or we can automate the population of exchange rates?
Does SFDC provide any out of the box  functionality for currency conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Apex job on hourly basis to fetch the exchange rate and store in a object as below.

CurrencyConverter is the class which fetch the conversion rate from yahoo and Store in a custom object called Rate. There are two fields one is Conversion_rate and Date. You can add more fields as required. I have used USD > INR conversion. You can update your currency in the URL parameter.

CurrencyConverterScheduler is the scheduler class which needs to be scheduled as per your requirement.

**Apex Class - CurrencyConverter**

```
global class CurrencyConverter{
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void convertCurrency(){
        Http httpProtocol = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        String endpoint = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22USDINR%22%29&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys';
        request.setEndPoint(endpoint); 
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response.getBody());
        String convRate = '';
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && 
                (parser.getText() == 'Rate')) {
                parser.nextToken();
                convRate = parser.getText();
            }
        }
        System.debug('convRate :'+convRate);       
        Rate__c rate = new Rate__c();
        rate.Conversion_rate__c = convRate;
        rate.Date__c = Date.today();
        insert rate;      
    }
}
```

**Apex Class - CurrencyConverterScheduler**

```
global class CurrencyConverterScheduler implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){
        CurrencyConverter.convertCurrency();
    }
}
```

Comment: My requirement would be to convert any currency to either Euro or USD . Also can you please let me know the exact yahoo portal from where exchange rates can be fetched . I have been searching that in vain  with forums telling me that yahoo finance has only stock info.

Comment: This is the Yahoo currency conversion site [link](http://finance.yahoo.com/currency-converter) where you can get all the exchange rates.

Comment: To use http rest API follow the steps below

**1** Start at the YQL Console [link](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console)
**2** In the upper left corner, make sure **Show Community Tables** is checked and **JSON** is selected in middle.
**3** Type **yahoo.finance.xchange** in the search field and click on the result.
**4** You'll see a query in the field **YOUR YQL STATEMENT** as **select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("EURUSD","GBPUSD")**
**5** You will get the HTTP REST URL in the field **THE REST QUERY** which I have used in the CurrencyConverter class.

Answer (score 0):

SFDC does not provide this functionality out of the box. There are apps in the AppExchange, however, that will do that. Please look for yourself, I don't have any experience with these myself.