# http callout to insert record in my custom currencyConversion object

Tags: webservices

I have a custom currencyConversion object and i want to insert conversion rates on this object on daily basis using a web service(URL). I am new to salesforce integration. How can I achieve this?

Webservice I have is using :

```
From Currency, To Currency, Start Date, Conversion Rate, Fiscal Period.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Apex job on daily basis to fetch the exchange rate and store in the currencyConversion object. To get the conversion rates you can use any standard standard service provider like [Yahoo currency conversion site](http://finance.yahoo.com/currency-converter/#from=USD;to=EUR;amt=1).

I had posted almost similar solution in [this SFSE link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76140/currency-conversion/76280#76280). Hope this will help you to build your own solution.

> Update - How to Parse the webservice response

```
String resp = '{"data":{"base":"USD","date":"20160527","rates":[{"currency":"AUD","rate":1.7572},{"currency":"CAD","rate":1.80343},{"currency":"EUR","rate":1.6372},{"currency":"GBP","rate":1.24301},{"currency":"JPY","rate":1.8272},{"currency":"MXN","rate":2.0},{"currency":"NZD","rate":1.52788}]},"pagination":null,"error":null}';

String mycurrency;
Double  myrate = 0.0;
//resp is a JSON string
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(resp);
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'currency')) {
        parser.nextToken();
        mycurrency= parser.getText();
    }
    if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'rate')) {
        parser.nextToken();
        myrate= parser.getDoubleValue();
        System.debug('currency = '+ mycurrency+' rate = '+myrate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot saroj. This ia very helpful. I don't want to use standard yahoo currency conversion rates rather i have a web service so i guess i just need to change the end point url with mine ?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my solution you can use any webservice you want. If this helps you, can you please accept it as answer.

Comment: Hi Saroj , I am not able to parse the values with the solution you provided as there are many values of rates for different currencies. I want to insert these  rates corresponding to the currency in my sf object. Your solution will insert only one conversion rate. what if i want to insert so many rates corresponding to their currency codes. Could you please help. Do we have to write wrapper classes for this ?

Comment: Can you post the response with multiple values?

Comment: this is the web service i got.... {"data":{"base":"USD","date":"20160527","rates":[{"currency":"AUD","rate":1.7572‌​},{"currency":"CAD","rate":1.80343},{"currency":"JPY","rate":1.8272},{"currency":"MXN","rate":2‌​.0},{"currency":"NZD","rate":1.52788}]},"pagination":null,"error":null}                        From this web service i have to insert records in my object something like this- From Currency,To Currency,Start Date,Conversion Rate,Fiscal Period
GBP,USD,5/13/16,1.46850000,May 2016 - P8FY16
EUR,USD,5/13/16,1.11500000,May 2016 - P8FY16

Comment: @Ridhi - Please check my updated answer on how to parse the response.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tested this updated code and it is working fine. Will this always give me the right values of rate for corresponding currencies ?

Comment: @Ridhi Yes it will. If this solves your problem, can you please mark this as answer.